# Construction of a characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is it possible to construct a characteristic function (for a distribution) $\phi(t)$ such that $\phi(t) = t^{-1/4}$ for $16\leq t \leq 20$?

I tried the inversion formula, but didn't know how to prove that the resulting set function is a probability measure.

Comment: Alright, now I see how to do it using the inversion formula.

Comment: If you've answered the question using an [inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas), I think you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to construct a characteristic function (for a distribution) $\phi(t)$ such that $\phi(t) = t^{-1/4}$ for $16\leq t \leq 20$?

[Pólya’s theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions) can be used to construct such a $\phi$.  Here's a simple example:

[image: graph of $\phi$]

$
\phi(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1 - \frac{t}{32} & \text{if } 0 \leq t < 16  \\
\\
t^{-\frac{1}{4}} & \text{if } t \geq 16  \\
\\
\phi(-t) & \text{if t} \lt 0
\end{cases}
$

It's easily verified that the conditions of the theorem are met, so this $\phi$ is the characteristic function of an absolutely continuous symmetrical distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I know this theorem. But is it possible to prove without Polya's theorem? And in fact, it is also not easy to construct a desired function that is globally convex.

Comment: @epsilon: Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify which approaches you consider acceptable/unacceptable. (Presently, there's nothing to suggest avoiding Pólya’s theorem. Also, contrary to your comment, it seems quite easy to obtain the required convexity.)